# Sequential numbers for many rows inserted with auto-increment key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, auto-increment

- SQL Server 2008 R2
- A table with auto-increment key
- Many different threads have to batch insert rows in the table.

I would like to know how (if even it is possible) to insert the rows in a way that I'm absolutely sure that the keys of one thread's inserted rows will get sequential numbers.

For example if 2 threads are executing at the same time:

- Thread #1 insert 5 rows and get keys 1,2,3,4,5
- Thread #2 insert 5 rows and get keys 6,7,8,9,10

I must be sure not to get:

- Thread #1 rows get keys 1,3,4,8,9
- Thread #2 rows get keys 2,5,6,7,10

Obviously if each thread do some kind of loop and execute 5 times "INSERT INTO..." command it won't work because another thread can insert between.

But even if a thread use only one INSERT command to insert many rows, is it enough to guarantee the keys will be sequential ?

If yes, could you help me find where it is documented ? because I didn't.

If no, how is it possible to ensure that ?

---

EDIT Why I care of getting consecutive numbers:

It is mainly a performance concern, we actually have one integer not auto-increment column in a row, each thread lock the row, manually increment the column value by any number it needs, than release the row.

The problem with that is that only one thread can insert at a time, by testing we found that inserting rows in a new table auto-increment column, letting sql server manage identity assignment, was much faster.
Locking the entire table is not an option because it will result in the same problem as locking a common row.

The reason why I want to ensure that inserted row ids are sequential for a single thread insert is to reduce the need for code refactoring which actually works by keeping only the first number and the count, so the code can deduce what are the other numbers.

It is not a business concern to have the numbers being consecutives, so if it is impossible to do we will just have to keep each row number in an array instead but there is more code to refactor this way so I'm trying to avoid it if possible.

Please keep in mind that i'm totally aware that the design may not be ideal, but i'm working with a legacy "big ball of mud" system that I can't redesign much.

Comment: Are you having trouble with using an identity column?

Comment: A single insert would in fact keep them sequential. The bigger question is why do you care? Identity columns will have gaps naturally when an insert fails or a row is deleted. Being concerned about sequential identity values is a big red flag to me that there are some underlying design concerns.

Comment: If you care about which values you get in a primary key and why, you should not use auto-increment / identity columns.

Comment: @SeanLange I don't care if there is a gap between threads, I care only that there is no gap between one thread's inserted rows

Comment: It won't happen since it is a single insert but why does it matter?

Comment: @SeanLange please read my edit section it is explained why it matters.

You say it won't happen because it is a single insert ? I read that in some other discussions, but I would like to find it in the official documentation, I didn't

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Seems like the code is a little bit brittle but understand the concerns about refactoring. I don't know that you will find any official documentation on the topic but an insert, even a multiple row insert, is a single atomic operation. An identity is a FAR better approach then what you described by doing it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the help, looks like it could work with a single multiple row insert, I guess I will go that way and confirm it works with load tests

Comment: @SeanLange, I tested. A single `INSERT` does **not** guarantee that generated `IDENTITY` values would be sequential. See my answer.

Comment: @Jonathan - Why not just store the thread id (or some sort of batch identifier)?  Do you care about the ordering of the inserted rows _for a single thread_?  That would potentially be a very minor change.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I need to get N consecutive unique ids for each single thread, how could I do that with a thread id ?

Comment: What I'm getting at is, what do you do with the id later?  If you're inserting into the table, then reading back out and just spinning through results, the id of the row is potentially unimportant - you just want to get all the rows related to your thread.  If you're updating/inserting to another table the id is maybe important (if for some reason you can't do a single statement), but the fact that you're maintaining a list is slightly troubling (because I'm worried you start/end transactions somewhere I'm not expecting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious enough to test. On my virtual machine with SQL Server 2014 Express the answer is:

---

Generated `IDENTITY` values are **not** guaranteed to be sequential when multiple threads insert values. Even if it is a single `INSERT` statement that inserts several rows at once. (Under default transaction isolation level)

---

You can test it on your SQL Server 2008, but even if you don't see the same behaviour, it wouldn't be wise to rely on it, because it definitely changed in 2014.

Here is the full script to reproduce the test.

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dt] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [V] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_test] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**INSERT script**

```
WAITFOR TIME '22:23:24';
-- set the time to about a minute in the future
-- open two windows in SSMS and run this script (F5) in both of them
-- they will start running at the same time specified above in parallel.

-- insert 1M rows in chunks of 1000 rows

-- in the first SSMS window uncomment these lines:
--DECLARE @VarV int = 0;
--WHILE (@VarV < 1000)

-- in the second SSMS window uncomment these lines:
--DECLARE @VarV int = 10000;
--WHILE (@VarV < 11000)

BEGIN

    WITH e1(n) AS
    (
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
    ) -- 10
    ,e2(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e1 AS b)    -- 10*10
    ,e3(n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM e1 CROSS JOIN e2)         -- 10*100
    ,CTE_rn
    AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) AS rn
        FROM e3
    )
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[test]
        ([dt]
        ,[V])
    SELECT
        SYSDATETIME() AS dt
        ,@VarV
    FROM CTE_rn;

    SET @VarV = @VarV + 1;

END;
```

**Verifying the results**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT 
        [V]
        ,MIN(ID) AS MinID
        ,MAX(ID) AS MaxID
        ,MAX(ID) - MIN(ID) + 1 AS DiffID
    FROM [dbo].[test]
    GROUP BY V
)
SELECT
    DiffID
    ,COUNT(*) AS c
FROM CTE
GROUP BY DiffID
ORDER BY c DESC;
```

This query calculates the `MIN` and `MAX` `ID` for each `V` (each chunk of 1000 inserted rows). If all `IDENTITY` values were generated sequentially, the difference between `MAX` and `MIN` IDs would always be exactly 1000. As we can see in the results, this is not the case:

**Result**

```
+--------+------+
| DiffID |  c   |
+--------+------+
|   1000 | 1940 |
|   2000 |    6 |
|   3000 |    3 |
|   1759 |    2 |
|   1477 |    2 |
|   1522 |    1 |
|   1524 |    1 |
|   1529 |    1 |
|   1538 |    1 |
|   1546 |    1 |
|   1548 |    1 |
|   1584 |    1 |
|   1585 |    1 |
|   1589 |    1 |
|   1597 |    1 |
|   1606 |    1 |
|   1611 |    1 |
|   1612 |    1 |
|   1620 |    1 |
|   1630 |    1 |
|   1631 |    1 |
|   1635 |    1 |
|   1658 |    1 |
|   1663 |    1 |
|   1675 |    1 |
|   1731 |    1 |
|   1749 |    1 |
|   1009 |    1 |
|   1038 |    1 |
|   1049 |    1 |
|   1055 |    1 |
|   1086 |    1 |
|   1102 |    1 |
|   1144 |    1 |
|   1218 |    1 |
|   1225 |    1 |
|   1263 |    1 |
|   1325 |    1 |
|   1367 |    1 |
|   1372 |    1 |
|   1415 |    1 |
|   1451 |    1 |
|   1761 |    1 |
|   1793 |    1 |
|   1832 |    1 |
|   1904 |    1 |
|   1919 |    1 |
|   1924 |    1 |
|   1954 |    1 |
|   1973 |    1 |
|   1984 |    1 |
|   2381 |    1 |
+--------+------+
```

In most cases, indeed, `IDENTITY` values were assigned sequentially, but in 60 cases out of 2000, they were not.

---

How to deal with it?

I personally prefer to use [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx), rather than locking the table or increasing transaction isolation level.

But, end result is the same - you have to make sure that `INSERT` statements are not running in parallel.

---

In SQL Server 2012+ it is worth testing the behaviour of the new `SEQUENCE` feature. Specifically, the [`sp_sequence_get_range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878352.aspx) stored procedure that generates a range of sequence values from a sequence object. Let's leave this exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 1):

use transactions.
The transaction will lock the table until you will commit so no other transaction will start until the previous is ended, so the identity values are safe

Comment: As explain in the edit section of my post, doing that will result in the same problem than locking a common row

Comment: @Jonathan a transaction alone is not enough. You must also **lock** the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an exclusive lock on the whole table as follows.

Please note the `X` in `TABLOCKX`- this makes the lock exclusive.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- select one dummy row, and set an exclusive lock 
-- on the whole table (TABLOCKX)

SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM yourtab
WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK);

-- Your INSERT statements goes here:
INSERT INTO yourtab(....) ... 

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: I explained in my post that I don't want to lock the table for performance concern, there will be a lot of threads inserting concurrently

Comment: @Jonathan: If you don't want to lock the table, the multiple transactions might occur in the same time, so your identity values are not guaranteed to be in a strict sequential order. This is a normal behaviour of every OLTP system.

Comment: @Jonathan: If you don't want to lock the table, the multiple transactions might occur in the same time, so your identity values are not guaranteed to be in a strict sequential order. This is a normal behaviour of every OLTP system. Either you gain exclusive access to that table (and by this you have a total control over it) or you allow this kind of "discrepancies". Or use an external counter table  where you can "reserve" (update) the required number of IDs. But in this case you have to know beforehand the number of rows you want to insert and you have to assign the ID by yourself

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL Sever? From SQL Server 2012 on, you can create so-called **sequences.** These are objects which create unique numbers to the caller. 
Sequences are guaranteed to be thread-safe.

In your case, you would need a sequence which increases by step 5:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE myseq 
AS int
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 5
```

In your thread, you could then retrieve the next value with `NEXT VALUE`:

```
DECLARE @var int ;
SET @var = NEXT VALUE FOR myseq ;
```

You could then use this value and insert the values in your table. With this, you could go without locking your tables.

Comment: I'm assuming the "5 rows" thing was only an example, and the real number inserted will be different.